# How to separate post titles with a comma in the loop?

Tags: loop

How do I list all my posts with a comma (but not after the last post)...

```
<?php 
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'day_time',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'mon-night')),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'posts_per_page'         => '20',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true,
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'separater'                         => ', ',
    'orderby'                => 'modified',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php   }
} else { ?>

<?php }

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>


<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of outputting everything immediately, save it to a variable so you can conditionally add a comma (and presumably a space) between items:

```
<?php
// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    // Save the number of posts found
    global $wp_query;
    $total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
    // Set a counter variable
    $i=0;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Save the title to a variable instead of outputting
        $output .= get_the_title();
        // Increment the counter each time
        $i++;
    }
    // Outside the loop, since you only want 1 comma each time
    if($i != $total_posts) {
        // Add a comma and a space
        $output .= ', ';
    }
    // Last but not least, display the output
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: I prefer it to in the `<?php` blah blah `?>` format, can your solution be adapted this way?

Comment: Of course. But this whole thing is PHP, so all it does is tell your website to stop parsing PHP and start parsing PHP, stop parsing PHP and start parsing PHP.

Comment: I'd like to use `<?php the_title(); ?>` rather than `$output .= get_the_title();`.

Comment: You could do that by checking whether this is the last item and if not, echo the `', '` inside the `while` loop, instead of outside of it.